# Como consultar vários select em somente uma linha sql para obter 7 resultado diários

Tags: php, sql

```
SELECT count(*) as dias  FROM users WHERE DATE(created_at)  = CURRENT_DATE()-0
```

Tenho esta linha de sql que soma todos registros feitos do dia atual. Mas eu quero dos 7 dias seguidos teria como fazer as 7 em somente uma linha sql.

Comment: `SELECT count(*) as dias  FROM users WHERE DATE(created_at)  = CURRENT_DATE()-7`

Comment: okay mais isto da to total de todos os dias eu quero um por vez tipo se vc coloca 0 vem hj 1 amanha  deu pra entender

Comment: Sua pergunta está vaga, não deu para entender... Lembrando que: count(*) vai contar os registros retornados pela consulta, se quiser somar algo, use sum(campo).

Comment: Eu particularmene não vejo problemas em quebrar a sql em várias linhas, até mesmo a visualização e entendimento da mesma por outras pessoas fica melhor.

Comment: anderson entao vc surgere que faça 7 sql  pra gerar consultas  de todos  os dias ?

Comment: Aqui funcionou da forma com a qual te mandei

Comment: jakson sim funciona mais ela so me retorna uma data preciso de tipo seg ter qua qui sex sab dom , tentei colocar dentro de um for esta consulta  pra ir consultando os 7 dias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o seu campo "created_at" for um campo do tipo data e hora e você deseja ver a quantidade de cadastros nos últimos 7 dias quebrado por data, uma das formas de resolver seria assim:

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(created_at) as dia_semana, YEAR(created_at) AS ano, MONTH(created_at) as mes, DAY(created_at) as dias, count(*) as total
FROM users WHERE created_at > date_sub(NOW(), interval 7 day)
GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(created_at), YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at), DAY(created_at) 
ORDER BY YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at), DAY(created_at)
```

A função dayofweek retorna um número para o dia de semana, as funções year, month e day extraem ano mes e dia do campo data/hora

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-dayofweek-function.php

Comment: olha nao  era bem assim nao mais  ja ajudo muito  deu pra resolver muito obrigrado